# Download Successful now direct to next page?

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, download

I have a page where a text file is downloaded when I button is clicked.  When that happens I would then like to direct the user to a confirmation/more details page.

I am using visual studio 2008 and it is VB.Net in 3.5

Answer (score 0):

You should do the downloading in an iframe instead of redirecting and then monitor events of that iframe to see when it's done.  It's browser specific, but my colleague blogged about the events to expect in each browser.

http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/jake/archive/2009/06/18/events-to-expect-when-dynamically-loading-iframes-in-javascript.aspx

http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/jake/archive/2009/08/18/events-to-expect-when-dynamically-loading-iframes-in-javascript-take-2-thanks-firefox-3-5.aspx

When the download is done, you can set the location of the main window to redirect to the next page.